Using Pydantic Model for IDE support
I have created a simple pydantic model:
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class NameModel(BaseModel):
    name: str = Field(..., description="dummy description")  
    surname: str = Field(default=None, description="dummy description")

I created a function:
def simple_function(some_value: NameModel):
    return some_value.name

When calling simple_function, I get below as type hint:

(some_value: NameModel) -> str

How can I get name & surname fields in place of (some_value: NameModel) -> str without specifying each field again in  simple_function? like this
    def simple_function2(name: str,surname: str):
        user = NameModel(name = name,surname = surname)
        return user

I am using VS Code.

probably something analogous to https://stackoverflow.com/a/78813079/11107541

As far as I know there is no such feature in Pydantic.
Why don't you just call your function this way?
res = simple_function(
    NameModel(name="Name", surname="Surname") 
) 


This way you will have typehints and validation

Thank you for the response. The function will be exposed as part of a python package/utils etc, which means user needs to remember both simple_function & NameModel when calling simple_function. I am not sure if there is other way.
